# How Do Some Alarm Apps Play Audio for More than 30 Seconds?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, core-audio, alarm

I would like to write an Alarm app for iOS that will let the user select a song from their iTunes music library and play that song, regardless of its length, as the alarm sound.

Most apps appear to use a local or push notification to sound the alarm when the app is not in the foreground.  Everything I have read on Stack Overflow, Apple Documentation, and elsewhere on the internet says that the app must bundle the audio with the application and that the audio must not exceed 30 seconds in duration or the default sound will play instead, yet the Alarmy app, currently available on the app store at:

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/alarmy-morning-alarm-clock/id1163786766

will let the user pick a song from their music library, play it as the alarm tone (even if it is longer than 30 seconds), and continue to repeat the whole song if the user doesn't shut off the alarm.  So this proves that it is possible to do what I want to do.  Does anyone have any insight into how Alarmy does this?

Comment: Does this work even if you kill the app while waiting for the alarm?

Comment: Surprisingly, yes it does.